# Canonical handling of HTTPS request when SSL not supported

Tags: http, ssl, https, webserver

If a client is requesting a domain that does not have a valid CA signed certificate and the server not intend on supporting HTTPS but does support HTTP for this domain, what is the best way to handle this in the web server. Note, the server does handle requests for SSL (HTTPS) on other domains so it is listening on 443.

Example where this would apply is for multi sub-domains where the sub-domains are dynamically created and thus making it extremely difficult to register CA signed certificates.

I've seen people try to respond with HTTP error codes but these seem  moot as the client (browser) will first verify the certificate and will present the hard warning to the user before processing any HTTP. Therefore the client will only see the error code if they "proceed" past the cert warning.

Is there a canonical way of handling this scenario?

Answer (score 1):

There is no canonical way for this scenario. Clients don't automatically downgrade to HTTP if HTTPS is broken and it would be a very bad idea to change clients in this regard - all what an attacker would need to do to attack HTTPS would be to infer with the HTTPS traffic to make a client downgrade to unprotected HTTP traffic.

Thus, you need to make sure that the client either does not try to attempt to access URL's which do not work properly (i.e. don't publish such URL's) or to make sure that you have a working certificate for these subdomains, i.e. adapt the processes for creation of subdomains so that they not only have an IP address but also a valid certificate (maybe use wildcard certificates).

Answer (score 1):

Considering these websites don't have to work with SSL, the webserver should close all SSL connections for them in a proper way.

There is no canonical way for this, but [RFC 5246](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246) implicitly suggests to interrupt the handshake on the server side by using the user_cancel + close_notify alerts. How to achieve this is another question, it will be a configuration of the default SSL virtual host.

> user_canceled
>
> This handshake is being canceled for some reason unrelated to a
> protocol failure.  If the user cancels an operation after the
> handshake is complete, just closing the connection by sending a
> close_notify is more appropriate.  This alert should be followed
> by a close_notify.  This message is generally a warning.

Answer (score 0):

If you are dealing with subdomains, you probably can use a wildcard certificate for all of your subdomains.
Adding the CA certificate to your client will remove the warning (that's what companies do, no worry).
When hosting with Apache, for example, you can use VirtualDocumentRoot to add domains without editing your configuration. Have a look at the solution provided here : [Virtual Hosting in SSL with VirtualDocumentRoot](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48331079/7748072)

Comment: In the case proposed, wildcard certificates are not possible as wildcards only apply to the domain level 'starred', it must be the first character in the pattern and only one star is allowed. Browsers don't support wildcards for all sub levels past a star. Please assume that CA signed certificate is not possible.

Comment: I assume you don't want signed certificates because it would cost a lot in maintenance (generating CSR, requesting certificates, installing them), and wildcard certificates don't fill your needs because they are a partial answer only. Not because it is not possible. Moreover, my answer is forcing you to use SSL on servers that are not intended to use, and there is no need to add this functionality. In short, Steffen's answer is correct.